# How to Limit and Show an Error when the User Input Entered 2 Characters and Up in C#

Tags: c#

How can I show up an Error Message like this: "Error, please enter 1 character only" when a user inputs more than 2 characters in my program. This is a C# language.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lab_Activity_1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Char x;

            Console.Write("Enter a letter: ");
            x = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if ((x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z') || x >= 'a' && x <= 'z')
            {
                if (x == 'a' || x == 'A' || x == 'e' || x == 'E' || x == 'i' || x == 'I'
                            || x == 'o' || x == 'O' || x == 'u' || x == 'U')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(x + " is a Vowel letter.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(x + " is a Consonant letter.");
                }
            }
            else if (x >= 48 && x <= 57)
            {
                Console.Write("You entered a number, Please enter a character and try again. \n");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error! Please enter a valid character.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C and C# are two *extremely* different programming languages. Please don't add unrelated tags to your questions, no matter how similar their names might look. Also pay close attention to other tags, like `sharp` which is unrelated to C#. Always read the tag descriptions, if there are any.

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed that I accidentally input C.

Comment: first capture `Console.ReadLine` in a `string` and then check if it's `Length` is more than 1.  and to get the char just do `input[0]`.

Comment: @juharr hello, I'm new to C# language. Where should I put that?

Comment: Having a `string vowels = "AaEeIiOoUu";` and doing `vowels.Contains(char)` is a more compact way to check if a char is a vowel

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to capture the entire string they enter then you can check it's length.  Then you can check the character in the first index of the string.  Also I used `ToUpper` so you don't have to do comparisons with lower case letters.

```
namespace Lab_Activity_1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a letter: ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            if(input.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter one character.");
            }
            else if(input.Length > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter only one character.");
            }
            else if (input[0] >= 'A' && input[0] <= 'Z')
            {
                if (input[0] == 'A' || input[0] == 'E' || input[0] == 'I'
                            || input[0] == 'O' || input[0] == 'U')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(input[0] + " is a Vowel letter.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(input[0] + " is a Consonant letter.");
                }
            }
            else if (input[0] >= 48 && input[0] <= 57)
            {
                Console.Write("You entered a number, Please enter a character and try again. \n");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error! Please enter a valid character.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, may I also ask if how can I modify wherein if I enter a lowercase letter of 'a' then the output will also be the same lower case 'a'.

The output on that modified code will be like this:
Enter a letter: a
A is a Vowel letter.
Press any key to continue ...

But it needs to be the same case letter like this: 
Enter a letter: a
a is a Vowel letter.
Press any key to continue ...

Comment: @MiguelArcangelCastillo You can capture the input without the `ToUpper` then get the character to compare with `char c = input.ToUpper()[0];` then use `c` in the comparisons and `input[0]` in the output.

Comment: I don't know where to put that. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
if (line != null)
{
    if (line.Length == 1)
    {
        char c = line[0];
        Console.WriteLine("Character: '" + c + "', ASCII: " + (int)c);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error, please enter 1 character only");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error, null");
}
```